# WPF: Get all children of a window and assign the same KeyDown event to them

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using WPF to create a window with some controls of all kinds (buttons, textboxes, ...) in it.
Now I'm trying to assign one KeyDown event to all controls when the window has finished loading.
Unfortunately, I can't assign the event to the children of the window.

```
private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this); i++)
     {
         VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i).KeyDown += Common_KeyDownEvent; // doesn't work

     }
}

private void Common_KeyDownEvent(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{

        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
           // Do other stuff               
        }
}
```

*Error:* **'System.Windows.DependencyObject'** does not contain a 
    definition  for 'KeyDown' and no extension method 'KeyDown' accepting 
    a first argument of type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' could be found 
    (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Use `Keyboard.AddKeyDownHandler`. You have to do it this way, as KeyDown is an attached event, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.addkeydownhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why are you trying to add the event handler to every individual control? Just hook the event on the Window and let event bubbling do its job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```
 KeyBoard.AddKeyDownHandler(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i), Common_KeyDownEvent);
```

This should attach the event handler as you require.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i) is UIElement)
  (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i) as UIElement).KeyDown += Common_KeyDownEvent;
```

This bit of code will attach the event to the objects which actually have the event.